# curl -u equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, curl

I'm having trouble finding a working solution to pass the -u 'token' param from curl into subsequent web calls. I've tried HttpClient, WebClient, Flurl, but can't crack how to format post login requests correctly with the token. Can anyone point me to an example of some c# example with the equivalent of curl's -u?

This is from the Barracuda Load Balancer [API DOC](https://techlib.barracuda.com/attachments/download/LBADCv50/42049757/ADC_REST-API-V2-073115.pdf%20API%20DOC)

Login Request

```
$ curl -X POST \ -H "Content-Type:application/json" \ -d '{"username": "admin", "password": "admin"}' \ http://10.11.19.104:8000/restapi/v2/login  

Response:  
{"token":"eyJldsI6IjE0NjIzODQ0MTgiLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6ImUzZDFhY2IwNzlkZmQxMDZmMmRhODEwZGRm
MzFiNGI3IiwidXNlciI6InNlYW4ifQ=="}
```

Logout Request

```
$ curl -u 'J3sidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ5Jw=\n:' \ -X DELETE \ http://10.11.19.104:8000/restapi/v2/logout  

Response: { "msg": "Success" }
```

Here is my attempt to use the token:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NLog;

namespace Barracuda
{
    class Program
    {

        private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        public static String BaseUrl = "https://load.balancer.ip";
        public static String RestApi = "restapi/v2/";
        public static String LoginEndpoint = RestApi + "login";
        public static String LogoutEndpoint = RestApi + "logout";
        public static String VirtualUserGroups = RestApi + "virtual_service_groups";

        public class LoginCreds
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
        }

        public class LogoutMessage
        {
            public string msg { get; set; }
        }

        public class AuthToken
        {
            public string token { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //login
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(BaseUrl + "/" + LoginEndpoint);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                var creds = new LoginCreds {username = "myUsername", password = "myPassword"};
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(creds);
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }
            var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            AuthToken myToken;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                myToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthToken>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
                logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, myToken.token);
            }
            //logout
            request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(BaseUrl + "/" + LogoutEndpoint);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "DELETE";
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myToken.token));
            response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                 var logoutMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogoutMessage>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
                logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, logoutMessage.msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that some kind of common authentication scheme? How are we supposed to know how you have to interact with a random web service we don't know?

Comment: Added more detail. There is probably an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

FML - typo. Needed a space in the header after Basic.